# Can anyone tell me how to setup our own TOR private network in linux?

Tags: tor

I need to setup my own TOR private network  but I am not able to find any useful link. Please let me know if you have asap.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type in the following commands then hit Enter after each.
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install tor-browser

Tell me how it goes